# I use Xcode distributing app to App Store Connect. Xcode upload fail and show "ERROR ITMS-90037"

Tags: ios, xcode

I distribute my app to App Store Connect. Xcode run some process. Then Xcode upload fail and show `ERROR ITMS-90037`.

This project developed using Objective-C. I used Sublime Text finding following regular expression `[\x00-\x08\x0b-\x1f\x7f]`. I didn't find anything in my Info.plist.

This is my Info.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My App Name</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>sina</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>str</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>wx</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>str</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>qq</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>str</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>tencent</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>str</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>lineredsport</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.myteam.myapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        ...
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问媒体资料库</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问蓝牙</string>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问日历</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问相机</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>始终访问位置</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问位置</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>试用期间访问位置</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问麦克风</string>
    <key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问运动与健康</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>滚球体育会在修改头像和发布推荐时使用您的相机，是否允许?</string>
    <key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问提醒事项</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>DIN-Bold.TTF</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

following is full error message

> ERROR ITMS-90037: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing or could not be parsed. Please check it for embedded control characters."

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ITMS-90037 upload error stack overflow notes.

https://www.e-learn.cn/content/wangluowenzhang/1116413